# Facebook iOS SDK Graph Api Public Page Feed

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, sdk, public

Can anyone point me in the direction of a thorough tutorial on how to get a public page's post feed? I'd like to really understand what's going on rather than copying and pasting.  Even still I haven't found anything I could copy and paste that works.  I've managed to make some headway with the following code but the resulting json is not pretty and making extracting image urls virtually impossible (it doesn't require an appId, which I do actually have entered into the plist anyway).  I'd rather be using FBRequestConnection.  It doesn't seem like it'd be too challenging but I'm unfamiliar with the sdk and the documentation on this seems a bit wanting.

```
NSString *pageId = @"##################";
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php?format=json&id=%@", pageId];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
self.tags = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"#meditation", nil];

[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request
                                   queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                       completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response,
                                           NSData *data, NSError *connectionError)
 {
     QuoteItem *menuItem = [[QuoteItem alloc] init];
     if (data.length > 0 && connectionError == nil)
     {
         NSDictionary *fbFeed = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data
                                                                   options:0
                                                                     error:NULL];

         NSMutableArray *entries = [fbFeed objectForKey:@"entries"];
```

I was trying to keep it brief, but to further clarify I've tried using the instruction given by facebook here (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/page/feed#read) by doing the following:

```
[FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"/###########9055/feed"
                             parameters:nil
                             HTTPMethod:@"GET"
                      completionHandler:^(
                                          FBRequestConnection *connection,
                                          id result,
                                          NSError *error
                                          ) {
                          /* handle the result

                      }];
```

And I get this runtime error: "FBSDKLog: Error for request to endpoint '/164313873599055/feed': An open FBSession must be specified for calls to this endpoint." So I looked up FBSession (which is not mentioned at the destination of the aforementioned link) and tried to remedy the situation but I'm not sure how to set permissions.  What I have a tried led to a prompt for the user to allow access to their feed, which is not wanted.  I just want the user to see this darn public page feed without having to log in, without seeing anything facebook related in the app.

Which is why I was looking for a thorough tutorial to step a person through the above in one place.  These tutorials, I know, do exist for other aspects of iOS development and I was wondering if there was something similar for this case WITHOUT having to write an essay.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt that you had a look in the Facebook docs, because there it's all outlined:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/page/feed/#read

The call is

```
/{page_id}/feed
```

where `{page_id}` is the id of the Page you're looking for. You'll need to add an Access Token to the call.